# Can I insert image into another image in Polymer?

Tags: web, polymer

**What i have**

If I have two images (one includes frame and another includes the picture),

**My question**

can I show it in the same image by using Polymer? I think it looks like bitmap in android and I want to do in web but I really don't know how

Comment: How ever you do it, you need CSS to stack the two images on top each other and make it look like they are just one image.

Comment: @Adi I want to display this image in google map where I've marked location so It can't solve my problem. Anyway, thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example on how to place a picture over a picture. Since I didn't have any pictures i "faked" them with span tags. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/US8Y5gE47HHiMa6FFhOj?p=preview)

```
<style>
  .pic-one{
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
  }
  .pic-two{
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
  }
</style>

<div class='container'>
  <span class='pic-one'></span>
  <span class='pic-two'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it's not what I need.